# stacked paper but with top one at an angle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I was wondering if you can simulate two sheets of paper using Jquery but with the top sheet at an angle?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Could you please clarify as to what you mean with 'sheets of paper'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a live example to give you some ideas.  It doesn't use jQuery, just good ol' CSS.  Should work in modern browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/5UrJL/1/

Of course, you can use jQuery to control the CSS for the various sheets, in particular their position and rotation.

If you really want to use a jQuery plug-in, a search engine led me to this one:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rotation

with a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aflin/vbSMy/